# Is it valid to do K-means clustering on PCA-reduced data?

Tags: clustering, pca, k-means

[Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_digits.html) is the basic SKLearn tutorial on K-means.

They run PCA and then do K-means on reduced data. Can it radically affect the result? Will we get totally different clusters if we apply PCA on already clustered data?

Comment: The topic "k means after PCA" is like "is there life after love" - asked and answered numerous times on this site. Please try to search and read, before asking.

Comment: See this answer which in summary says: PCA mitigates the effect of outliers and hence in the presence of outliers, the results could be radically different. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12856/73547

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can radically affect the result.

You can get completely orthogonal clusters if the variances of the components are different by a large factor.